# Firebase CORS issue

Tags: reactjs, firebase, cors, firebase-hosting

I built a react app and I have deployed it on firebase. I have been getting this error whenever user searches.

```
Failed to load https://food2fork.com/api/search?key=0882376145a8bcae6c3cee&q=fish&count=50: Redirect from
    'https://food2fork.com/api/search?key=0882376145a8107c5946c3cee&q=fish&count=50' to
    'https://www.food2fork.com/api/search
    key=0882376145a8bcae390107c5946c3cee&q=fish&count=50'
    has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is 
present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://recipe-finder-26e0e.firebaseapp.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

As I am new to this one, I am unable to figure out how to enable CORS in firebase which I think is the problem. If anyone can tell me how to enable CORS I would be grateful Thank you.

Edit: Source code link --> https://github.com/AdiBev/Recipe-Finder

Update: I didn't understand in the beginning that CORS needs to be handled by back end. Thanks to @Ben. Ayoub for explaining it to me.

If it helps for any others like me who got same problem I found a great article and some proxies are mentioned there.
link ---> https://gist.github.com/jesperorb/6ca596217c8dfba237744966c2b5ab1e

Comment: Please add the source code that you've been using. Do not use links to deployed apps. URLs might change and then this question is not useful in the future.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the link. I have added the source code now.

Comment: Please add the relevant piece of source code in the question. Not as a link to repo.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Ben. Ayoub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10434643/ben-ayoub)'s solution it could be worth you looking into [HTTPS Callable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) functions if it's only your app trying to communicate with the Function and it's not part of a wider external API.

They work similar to HTTPS endpoints but get rid of the headaches of CORS.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

export const listener = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  if (data) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument');
  }

  return {
    some: 'json',
  };
}
```

You don't need to use the `request` and `response` parameters like in the HTTP Endpoint Cloud Function.

It accepts JSON as it's `context` and returns a simple JSON object.

**Edit**

To answer your original question, the cloud functions can make use of CORS

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });

export const listener = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {
    return;
  });

  // cloud function logic

  res.json({ some: 'json' });
});
```

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me where would I be adding this code? In firebase functions index.js file? I have no idea whatsoever about this It would be helpful if you can tell me how to do this in detail. Thank you.